# howto use "No Fast Forward" flag when merging branches in git with IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

I am using Idea 13.0.2 and I want to merge my 'feature' branch in the 'develop' branch with the "--no-ff" flag.

If from Idea, I checkout the "develop" branch and invoke the "merge" operation (all this from the "Git Branches" popup), the actual merge command executed by Idea is:

```
git merge feature/f4
```

I'd like it to be

```
git merge feature/f4 --no-ff
```

I have search a way to add this flag in Idea. The documentation reference a 'Merge Branches Dialog' https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/merge-branches-dialog.html with such a check box, but I have not been able to get it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: the only think I use idea/git integration for is a simple commit/push if I'm on a feature branch, everything else is just safer to do in the command line.

Comment: I agree that learning with command line is a good and "safe" thing. But then, automate thing can save some time. And as IDEA clearly log the git commands it executes, it should be safe enough for me. At least, it save me the typing of my branch name ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just go to VCS - Git - Merge Changes, and on the following dialog tick "No fast forward":

[image]

Comment: thanks bitoiu, I was not triggering the merge from here, but from the "Git branches" popup, which does not display this dialog.
using the menu "VCS / Git / Merge changes" does display it.

Comment: Any chances it can be configured by default? Didn't find that in settings.

Comment: This is great (and i am using this currently) BUT i am working on around 10 different git repos so i need to do that flow 10 times, even if i am in a "common branch" environment.

Status bar > merge allow me to merge all the branches in a move BUT don't allow me to set the "no fast forward " (--no-ff) option

Answer (score 6):

For new IntelliJ Idea versions:

Simply, From `Git` menu > `merge`,
then select the **target branch**
then `Modify options` by selection **`--no-ff`**

[image]